# Reading partitioned data (parquets) using dask with 'int64' vs 'int64 not null'

Tags: python, pandas, dask, parquet

I have this annoying situation where some of my parquet files have:

> x: int64

and others have

> x: int64 not null

and ergo (in dask 2.8.0/numpy 1.15.1/pandas 0.25.3) I can't run the following:

```
test: Union[pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, np.ndarray] = dd.read_parquet(input_path).query(filter_string)[input_columns].compute()
```

Anyone know what I can do short of upgrading dask/numpy (as I know the latest dask/numpy seem to work)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you know which files contain the different dtypes, then it's best to re-process them (load/convert dtype/save).

If that's not an option, then you can create a dask dataframe from delayed objects with something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from dask import delayed
import dask.dataframe as dd

@delayed
def custom_load(fpath):
    df = pd.read_parquet(fpath)
    df = df.astype({'x': 'Int64'}) # the appropriate dtype
    return df

delayed = [custom_load(f) for f in files] # where files is the list of files
ddf = dd.from_delayed(delayed) # can also provide meta option if known
```