# Dask delayed data mismatch

Tags: python, pandas, dask, dask-dataframe, dask-delayed

I wish to combine many dataframes into 1 dataframe with dask. However when I try to read those dataframes with dd.from_delayed(parts, meta=types) I get the error `Metadata mismatch found in 'from_delayed'`.

**The full error:**

```
Metadata mismatch found in `from_delayed`.

Partition type: `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame`
+--------+-------+----------+
| Column | Found | Expected |
+--------+-------+----------+
| 'col3' | -     | object   |
+--------+-------+----------+
```

I know this is because the dataframes I wish to combine do not have the same columns. Data that not exists in a column should be marked as NA. Setting verify_meta=False will silence these errors, but will lead to issues downstream since some of the partitions don't match the metadata.

**The code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar
from dask import delayed
import os

def dict_to_dataframe(dict):
    return pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)


data_a = {'col1': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]], 'col2': [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]]}        
data_b = {'col1': [[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24]], 'col3': [[25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32]]}

parts = [delayed(dict_to_dataframe)(fn) for fn in [data_a, data_b]]
types = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'], dtype=object)
ddf_result = dd.from_delayed(parts, meta=types)

print()
print('Write to file')
file_path = os.path.join('test.hdf')
with ProgressBar():
    ddf_result.compute().sort_index().to_hdf(file_path, key=type, format='table')

written = dd.read_hdf(file_path, key=type)
```

Comment: Please ask one question at a time. You need to align the dataframes first - they can’t have different columns. And you can set a subset of columns as string type with e.g. `df[[col1, col3]] = df[[col1, col3]].astype("string")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dataframes you want to combine need to have the same columns. A solution can be adding the columns that are missing to each dataframe so that they can be combined.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask import delayed
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar

def dict_to_dataframe(dict, all_columns):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)

    # Add missing columns and sort columns   
    missing_columns = list(set(all_columns).difference(df.columns)) 
    df = df.reindex(columns=sorted([*df.columns.tolist(), *missing_columns]))

    # Set new column type to object
    df[missing_columns] = df[missing_columns].astype(object)

    return df


data_a = {
    101: [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
    110: [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]],
}
data_b = {
    105: [[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24]],
    130: [[25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32]],
}


all_columns = [101, 105, 110, 130, 140]
parts = [delayed(dict_to_dataframe)(fn, all_columns) for fn in [data_a, data_b]]
types = pd.DataFrame(columns=all_columns, dtype=object)
ddf_result = dd.from_delayed(parts, meta=types)

with ProgressBar():
    ddf_result.compute().sort_index().to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

To allow use of `delayed` for creation of a single dataframe, it's possible to enforce a specific schema during formation of the `delayed` objects. Building [on a relevant answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68628636/10693596), the `dict_to_dataframe` can be modified to incorporate the business logic, for example:

```py
def dict_to_dataframe(dict, common_columns):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
    # keep only the columns known to be common to all dataframes
    df = df[common_columns]
    return df
```

Make an appropriate modification to the `meta` example, the rest of the code should work. Here's the full snippet:

```py
import dask.dataframe as dd
import pandas as pd
from dask import delayed
from dask.diagnostics import ProgressBar


def dict_to_dataframe(dict, common_columns):
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dict)
    # keep only the columns known to be common to all dataframes
    df = df[common_columns]
    ...
    return df


data_a = {
    "col1": [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8]],
    "col2": [[9, 10, 11, 12], [13, 14, 15, 16]],
}
data_b = {
    "col1": [[17, 18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23, 24]],
    "col3": [[25, 26, 27, 28], [29, 30, 31, 32]],
}

common_columns = ["col1"]

parts = [delayed(dict_to_dataframe)(fn, common_columns) for fn in [data_a, data_b]]
types = pd.DataFrame(columns=common_columns, dtype=object)
ddf_result = dd.from_delayed(parts, meta=types)

print("Write to file")
file_path = "test.csv"
with ProgressBar():
    ddf_result.compute().sort_index().to_csv(file_path, index=False)

written = dd.read_csv(file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In fact I try to combine all the data instead of only keeping the common columns. Columns that not exist in the other dataframe should receive NA values.

Comment: That's a good exercise for you to check if you understand this answer well!

Comment: I understand that it is not possible to combine the dataframes when the columns do not match. Apart from that doesn't your answer do what I wish to perform.